# How to get original SQL error message on client-side using Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, exception, dapper

I would like to tell my case with using an example.

Let's say we have store procedure and the procedure contains this couple line of SQL code

```
BEGIN TRY  
    -- Generate a divide-by-zero error.  
    SELECT 1/0;  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    throw
END CATCH;  
GO
```

and of course if we execute this sp it returns divide by zero exception:

> Divide by zero error encountered

Is it possible to take SQL throwing message with Dapper?
here is dapper request call

```
 var data = sqlConnection.QueryFirstOrDefault<response>(QueryConstants.SpXXX,
 parameters, null, Constants.DAPPER_TIMEOUT, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

I am using sql server 2017 and Dapper 1.50.4.0

[Github Issue #959](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/959)

Comment: what do you mean "Is it possible to take SQL throwing message with Dapper?" ? can you rephrase that?

Comment: Yes. That's definitely what I am looking for. I would like to take SQL throwing message if its possible. @MarcGravell

Comment: Am I correct that you want to get original error message thrown by SQL SERVER on client-side (C#)?

Comment: for sure @IvanStarostin

Comment: does the exception happen before or after the data?

Comment: they are all in a transaction if there was an exception the changes are not committed. before and after for now doesn't make sense for now too me. @MarcGravell

Comment: @arslanaybars the transaction doesn't matter - we're not talking about what gets committed: we're talking about how the TDS is processed by the client; and before or after is **key** here - sorry, but it is. "Does your query do a `select` before the line that throws" is a very important question. Meaning: `select 42; DoSomethingThatFails();` can behave completely differently to `DoSomethingThatFails();` by itself

Comment: @MarcGravell sorry I didn't understand well. I have a try catch block and throw unexpected while the working. in my example, it throws when the select statement is working.

Comment: @arslanaybars it would probably be more useful to discuss this if we had a concrete example of *real* (or at least: more real) SQL we could look at. But: does the `Query<T>(...).FirstOrDefault()` workaround (in my answer) work?

Comment: @MarcGravell actually after your answer I understand there is no easy way to use and I don't want to this logic into my solution. I decide to log the throws in DB level to write and sp and this sp record the throws into a table a  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql  I don't take it to the client. I will add a track for dapper issue in GitHub. thank you for your help.

Comment: It would help to have a code example that actually demonstrates your issue. The code you show is too simple, leading to too simple answers.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the exception in your stored procedure is happening *after* the first result grid. This issue appears to be a subtle difference between `Query<T>` and `QueryFirstOrDefault<T>`. You can workaround it by using:

```
var item = Query<T>(...).FirstOrDefault();
```

which *does* throw in the expected way. I will investigate what is happening - I strongly suspect that it is the `CommandBehavior.SingleResult` hint (that dapper uses in `QueryFirstOrDefault`) preventing errors *after* the first grid being observed.

I recommend logging an issue on github, so I/we can track it.

Edit: confirmed - it is `SingleResult` doing this; here's a raw ADO.NET example to illustrate, where `foo` is a stored procedure that does `select 42;` before throwing an exception:

```
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "foo";

    // if SingleResult is omitted, the error is observed
    // using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())

    // if SingleResult is specified, the error is not observed
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
    {
        do
        {
            while (reader.Read()) { } // ignore the rows in the grid
        } while (reader.NextResult());
    }
}
```

The fix here is probably for me to just remove all the `SingleResult` hints, for example [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L1180-L1181) (there are more than just those, but these are the ones that apply in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Is a bit late but you could use a select statement in the catch section

```
BEGIN TRY  
    -- Generate a divide-by-zero error.  
    SELECT ':),ok';  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    SELECT ':(,'+ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH;
```

and for data result, chek multi Query Dapper Doc.

```
 using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, new {InvoiceID = 1}))
    {
        var invoice = multi.First<T>();
        var confirm = multi.ReadSingle<string>();
    }
```

[dapperDoc](https://www.learndapper.com/dapper-query/selecting-multiple-results)

Comment: Please see the other answer and all comments. This doesn't fix the issue.